# C++ function that works like substr() in PHP

Tags: c++

```
char * extract(FILE * handle, int from, int len=0)
{
    long fsize = filesize(handle);
    fseek(handle, from, SEEK_SET);
    len = (len > 0) ? fsize : fsize;
    char * new_data = new char[len];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        new_data[i] = getc(handle);

    return new_data;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * file1 = fopen("output.txt", "rb");
    char * buffer = extract(file1, 0);
}
```

I wanted to make a function similar to substr() in PHP, but that works for binary files rather text only, and the above is what I came up with. It seems to work, but I wanna know if I used the right approach.

Comment: Lots of things that you should not do here, but the most glaring issues are that you read one char at a time (performance killer), you try to overread if `len == 0` and `from != 0` and finally that this is really C code, not C++.

Comment: What does this statement do? "len = (len > 0) ? fsize : fsize;"  It sets  len to fsize regardless if len is non-zero.  Bug?

Comment: should be "long from" to avoid problems on large files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `for {}` loop, use

```
fread(new_data, 1, len, handle)
```

Also,

`len = (len > 0) ? fsize : fsize`

always sets len to filesize.  Maybe you wanted:

`len = (len > 0) ? len : fsize`